# Cometchat in use?

Tags: add-on

Does anyone have CometChat on their EEsite? If so, does it work as promised, and installation is as easy as promised? Am i wrong but do you need to add global variable in every single template that you have build in ExpressionEngine or that chat toolbar wont appear?

And most important, i have already some and more javascript on my site, so might that be a problem?

And last but not least, does this software work thru Forum Module when it is run via regular template?

Thanks.
FinPete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cometchat in my site forums now with success. So i think i can give a positive "thumbs up" to this software, even tho it has been online only 24 hours so far.

But i think that this is a low-cost solution for rapid chatting for logged in users, and more. (there is guest chat available but i dont find that very usefull).

Answer (score 0):

I've used CometChat, but not an EE site.  Installation is fairly straightforward, and yes, it was a snippet of code in the footer of the site (this was on MyBB actually).  If you have your Footer in a snippet, embed or LV, this should be a breeze to install.

CometChat is fully separate from EE so isn't impacted by EE's template parser.  It shouldn't matter how you run the Forum, so long as you have that snippet.

Comment: Hi Lisa, long time no see, hope all are good! :) Thanks for answering. Ok, I might give that software a try then...

Comment: Ok, i bought and installed it but it wont get the infos from EE data, ie. users, and when i login, toolbar is still saying that i need first to login if i want to use chat. Hehehe, so again, 50 bucks gone wild, i guess...

Comment: You'd need to build the integration to EE; as far as I know, that's not yet available.  They do have a refund period, though, so email them if it won't work. :)

Comment: Hi Lisa, ExpressionEngine integration is available there. Therefore i gave it a try. But now i just dont get this, first installation it didnt work at all, second i got my name on the list with avatar, but no-go with only logged in-chat, only guest chat works. Now i am willing to give away one license of Solspace TAG-module (4.2.1 atm. and if the transfer for this add on is possible) if someone can make this working for me. The actual integrate.php has about 150 lines of php codes and is quite simple, but not simple enough for me to make it working :)